# Length of the string Python

Tags: python

I need to check if a string is a [Pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) (a sentence using every letter of the alphabet at least once) or not. Why do I get the right solution only when I use `set`. Why it is not working with *string*?

```
def checkIfPangram(sentence):
    return len(set(sentence)) == 26 # answer is True

print(checkIfPangram('thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'))
```

This solution does not work:

```
def checkIfPangram(sentence):
    return len(sentence) == 26

print(checkIfPangram('thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog'))
```

Answer is not correct. With `len(sentence)` I get only False, but if I use `set(sentence)` then solution is correct.

Comment: What is your sentence were `'aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz'`? What would be the length of the string, and what would be the length of the set made from the string? Can you extrapolate to see what `set` is doing there?

Comment: Rather than asking someone else to explain this to you, you should investigate more on your own. What does `set(sentence)` return? Can you see the difference between `set(sentence)` and `sentence`? Do you see what `len` returns for each of those two values, and do you understand *why* it returns what it does in each case?

Comment: In short, a pangram is *not* just a string that contains exactly 26 characters. `'a'*26` is not pangram. It contains *each* of the 26 characters *at least* once.

Comment: (As a further exercise, you might want to think about how the possibility of `sentence` containing a mix of lowercase letters, uppercase letters, whitespace, punctuation, etc, would require the definition to change.)

Comment: Just because the length of the set is 26 doesn't mean that the sentence is a pangram. What if the sentence contained non-alpha characters (e.g., numbers, whitespace)

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable of type String.
Initialize the String variable to a non-null value.
Call the Java String length() method.
Hold the value of the String length in a variable for future use.

Comment: This question is clearly tagged for Python, not Java. But even if this were a Java question, this isn't an answer. Please read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

The sentence to be analysed might contain digits or whitespace and therefore cannot be a pangram even though the set of its characters might have a length of 26.

A more robust approach might be:

```
import string
def isPangram(sentence):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(sentence.lower()))) == string.ascii_lowercase
```